# promise.all и Event loop

Tags: javascript, promise

Насколько я понял принцип работы Event Loop, при выполнении кода промисы попадают в очередь Microtask queue и затем выполняются поочередно, потому что java script работает в один поток.

Вместе с тем, метод Promise.all() выполняет промисы параллельно.
Вот пример кода:

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "one"); 
}); 
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "two"); 
});
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "three");
});
var p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "four");
});


Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4]).then(value => { 
  console.log(value);
});
```

Результат выполнения скрипта через 1 секунду: `[ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ]`
То есть выполнение и правда выглядит параллельно.

Вместо setTimeout() я решил дать промисам долгую задачу и измерить время выполнения каждого промиса.

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  let start = new Date().getTime();

  let i = 1;
  while (i < 1e10) {
    i++;
  }
  let end = new Date().getTime();
  console.log(`p1: ${(end - start)/1000}s`);
  resolve(i);

}); 
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  let start = new Date().getTime();

  let i = 1;
    while (i < 1e10) {
      i++;
    }
    let end = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(`p2: ${(end - start)/1000}s`);

    resolve(i);

});
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let start = new Date().getTime();

  let i = 1;
    while (i < 1e10) {
      i++;
    }
    let end = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(`p3: ${(end - start)/1000}s`);

    resolve(i);

});
var p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let start = new Date().getTime();

  let i = 1;
    while (i < 1e10) {
      i++;
    }
    let end = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(`p4: ${(end - start)/1000}s`);

    resolve(i);

});

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4]).then(value => { 
  console.log(value);
});
```

На выходе:

```
p1: 11.456s
p2: 11.426s
p3: 11.44s
p4: 11.438s
[ 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000 ]
```

Получается, параллельно промисы все же не выполняются.
Почему же тогда с setTimeout() получается параллельно?

Comment: ты неправильно используешь конструктор Promise: код в нем выполняется синхронно.

Comment: Потому что реальное выполнение чего-либо длится всего несколько микросекунд (затраты на работу функции resolve), и оно последовательное. Всё остальное время — просто ожидание секунды, прописанной в setTimeout, в течение которой никто ничего нигде никак не выполняет, поэтому о параллельном или последовательном выполнении говорить вообще нет смысла (ведь ничего не выполняется)

Answer (score 4):

`Promise.all` - **НЕ** выполняет промисы параллельно, он их вообще не выполняет. Данная функция *возвращает новый Promise*, который разрешается когда все переданные Promise успешно завершились.

"Запускается" Promise в момент вызова конструктора, при этом функция, которая передается в конструктор [выполняется сразу же синхронно](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-promise-executor), например:

```js
console.log('before one ctr');
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('one ctr');
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, "one");
});
console.log('before two ctr');
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('two ctr');
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "two");
});
console.log('before three ctr');
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('three ctr');
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, "three");
});
console.log('before four ctr');
var p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('four ctr');
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "four");
});


Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4]).then(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

В примере выше видно, что сообщения выводятся последовательно, и асинхронность достигается только за счет использования *асинхронной* функции `setTimeout`. Если ее убрать, как это было сделано в примере в вопросе - будет обычное синхронное выполнение кода, которое эквивалентно тому же коду совсем без Promise.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript код всегда синхронный (выполняется в одном потоке). Асинхронно выполняется исключительно ожидание коллбэка из нативного кода браузера (HTTP запросы, чтение файлов, таймеры и т.д. исполняются в отдельных потоках условного браузера). Результат асинхронного вызова встает с коллбэком в очередь - цикл событий.

> В итоге, нагрузив синхронный поток исполнения JavaScript вы на корню убили асинхронность, так как результаты и коллбэки просто не могут поступить на исполнение.

```
const sleep = (timeout = 1000) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout, timeout));

const log = (timeout) => console.log('Finished', timeout);
sleep(3).then(log)
sleep(1).then(log)
sleep(0).then(log)

Finished 1
Finished 0
Finished 3
```

Promise.all позволяет запустить на ожидание коллбека параллельное сразу несколько промисов. Это его основное отличие от конструкции async/await.

```
const logAsync = async (timeout = 1000) => {
    console.log('Finished async', await sleep(timeout));
}

(async function() {
    await logAsync(3);
    await logAsync(1);
    await logAsync(0);
})();

Finished async 3
Finished async 1
Finished async 0
```

Promise.all срабатывает вместе с последним разрешенным промисом - именно это обеспечивает параллельное ожидание коллбеков. Браузер не ждет исполнения промисов поочередно и сразу перескакивает на новый из массива.

```
(async function() {
    console.time('Promise(all)');
    await Promise.all([sleep(3), sleep(1), sleep(0)]);
    console.timeEnd('Promise(all)');
})();

Promise(all): 3.877197265625ms
```

Comment: что за "параллельное ожидание"? _Promise.all позволяет запустить на ожидание коллбека параллельное сразу несколько промисов._ - перефразируй пожалуйста, совсем непонятно что тут написано

Comment: @Grundy "Браузер не ждет исполнения промисов поочередно и сразу перескакивает на новый из массива."

Comment: Понятнее не стало, поменяй в самом ответе, сейчас даже слова в предложении не согласованы между собой

Comment: Правильно я понял, что Promise.all() ожидает завершения всех полученных промисов. И если в каждом промисе есть setTimeout(), то после запуска первого таймера в промисе, сразу запускается второй таймер, потом третий и т.д. То есть нет ожидания завершения каждого таймера. Получается параллельная работа

Comment: @Павел да, именно так.